# Login ASP.NET usando Oracle PL/SQL y C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

Tengo un pequeño login con dos campos de texto (correo y numero de documento), los cuales a la hora de darle al botón "ingresar" quiero que se valide en mi stored procedure, pero me muestra un error de excepción:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto, error en la linea 31.

Línea 29:             com.Parameters.Add("id_usu_numerodocumento", Convert.ToInt32(numeroDocumento.Text.Trim()));
Línea 30:             com.Connection = conexion;
Línea 31:             int result = (Int32)com.ExecuteScalar();
Línea 32: 
Línea 33:             if (result == 1)
```

Mi código c# es el siguiente:

```
string con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectOrcl"].ConnectionString;
            //conexión a la base de datos
            OracleConnection conexion = new OracleConnection(con);
            conexion.Open();
            OracleCommand com = new OracleCommand("INGRESO_USUARIO", conexion);
            com.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com.Parameters.Add("usu_email", correoElectronico.Text.Trim());
            com.Parameters.Add("id_usu_numerodocumento", Convert.ToInt32(numeroDocumento.Text.Trim()));
            com.Connection = conexion;
            int result = (Int32)com.ExecuteScalar();

            if (result == 1)
            {
                Response.Redirect("admin/dashboard.aspx");
            }
            if (result == 0)
            {
                Response.Redirect("ingreso.aspx");
            }
            conexion.Close();
```

Y mi procedimiento:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INGRESO_USUARIO
(
    usu_email varchar,
    id_usu_numerodocumento int
)
AS
    usuNumeroDoc INT;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO usuNumeroDoc  FROM LA_USUARIO WHERE usu_email = usu_email AND id_usu_numerodocumento = id_usu_numerodocumento;
END;
```

Si el COUT es igual a 1, pasa, si es igual a 0, no pasa.

Gracias por su ayuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conseguí realizarlo al enviar un parametro OUT de tipo RefCursor en el procedimiento de Oracle:

```
--PROCEDIMIENTO PARA INGRESAR AL SISTEMA SEGÚN CORREO Y NUMERO DE DOCUMENTO
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INGRESAR_SISTEMA
(
    email VARCHAR,
    numeroDoc INT,
    registros out sys_refcursor
)
AS
BEGIN
     OPEN registros FOR SELECT COUNT(*) FROM LA_USUARIO WHERE USU_EMAIL = email AND ID_USU_NUMERODOCUMENTO = numeroDoc;
END;
```

Y en C# tomé el valor de esa posición y lo almacené en una variable para comprararla:

```
string valor = ds.Rows[0]["Count(*)"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes leer este tutorial.

**https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/calling-oracle-stored-procedures-from-microsoft-net/**

Tienes que definir al menos un parametro como OUT en tu procedimiento
ammacenado o bien, puedes crear una función.

Saludos.